# SQL Stored Procedure to Merge 2 tables together

Tags: sql-server

I wrote two stored procedures that insert into a table the actual Production.  Then inserts in the forecast after that.  I want production first then forecast.  What it is doing if I run production first it works perfectly.  If I then run forecast and their is Production and Forecast in the same months it is duplicating Production then it runs the forecast.  I have tried Distinct I tried in one Stored Procedure but in one table it is P_Date in one table it is Outdate. I am not sure how to do it in one stored procedure.  It is starting forecast after production but where they are equal on dates it is duplicating production.  How do I stop this from happening?

PRODUCTION

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FORECAST_PRODUCTION]
    (PROPNUM,
        LEASE,
        OPERATOR,
        API,
        OUT_DATE,
    OIL,
    GAS)
    
SELECT DISTINCT     
    ac.PROPNUM,
       ac.LEASE,
        ac.OPERATOR,
        ac.API,
    mp.P_DATE as OUT_DATE,
    mp.OIL,
    mp.GAS
FROM [AC_PROPERTY] ac
INNER JOIN AC_PRODUCT mp
ON ac.PROPNUM = mp.PROPNUM
WHERE mp.P_DATE >= '1/31/2016' AND ac.ARLP_EVAL = 'YES' AND ac.PROPNUM ='V3UJ28DE65'
END

;
```

FORECAST

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FORECAST_PRODUCTION]
    (PROPNUM,
        LEASE,
        OPERATOR,
        API,
    OUT_DATE,
    GROSS_OIL,
    GROSS_GAS,
    SCENARIO)
    
SELECT DISTINCT
    ac.PROPNUM,
        ac.LEASE,
        ac.OPERATOR,
         ac.API,
     fcst.OUTDATE,
     ROUND(fcst.GROSS_OIL,0),
     ROUND(fcst.GROSS_GAS,0),
     fcst.SCENARIO
FROM [AC_PROPERTY] ac
INNER JOIN AC_MONTHLY fcst
ON ac.PROPNUM = fcst.PROPNUM
WHERE fcst.SCENARIO = 'ARLP_STRIP' AND ac.PROPNUM = 'V3UJ28DE65' AND FCST.OUTDATE >2/28/2022    

END;
```

[image]

Comment: Without sample data and desired output nobody can help you here. There are however multiple issues with the way your queries are dealing with dates. In your first query it is ambiguous what is the month and day. In the second query it is just plain broken because you are using an integer instead of a string representation. You should always use the YYYYMMDD format as it the only format that is always interpreted correctly.

Comment: I keep trying to add the image of the desired output and it is not letting me add it.

Comment: Images are nearly worthless for this kind of thing. Instead post consumable data. Things like create table statements and insert statements are great. Or create a sql fiddle.

Comment: are you trying to "merge" the data in forecast into the prior data so you have one row for each date?

Comment: Yes I want Date Oil Production Gas Production Oil Forecast Gas Forecast

Comment: I think you want the merge statement -- here is a tutorial https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-sql-merge-statement/